# Why does GetProcAddress throw an exception when implemented?

Tags: c++, winapi

This is what my header file contains:

```
extern HMODULE Ws_32;
extern HMODULE User32;
extern HMODULE Kernel32;
extern HMODULE Advapi32;

typedef int (WINAPI *fnMessageBox)(
    _In_opt_ HWND    hWnd,
    _In_opt_ LPCTSTR lpText,
    _In_opt_ LPCTSTR lpCaption,
    _In_     UINT    uType
);

struct API
{
    HMODULE User32;
    fnMessageBox _MessageBox;
};
```

And this is what my CPP file contains:

```
API Api;

VOID Tools::LoadApis(API Api)
 {
    if ((Api.User32 = GetModuleHandleW(L"USER32.DLL")) == ERROR)
    {
        Api.User32 = LoadLibraryW(L"USER32.DLL");
    }

    if (Api.User32)
    {
        Api._MessageBox = fnMessageBox(GetProcAddress(Api.User32, "MessageBox"));
    }
}

int main()
{
    Tools::LoadApis(Api); // not a part of the example
    Api._MessageBox(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

On the line, where i call

```
Api._MessageBox(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

after defining

```
Api._MessageBox = fnMessageBox(GetProcAddress(Api.User32, "MessageBox"));
```

I get a memory exception, as follows:

> Exception thrown at 0x00000000 in rat.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x00000000.

Comment: of course you and must get this exception. you not check that  `_MessageBox == 0`. and it is 0, because - not exist api with name `MessageBox`

Comment: in struct api i have clearly defined _MessageBox, and a function called MessageBox does exist, as you can see in the msdn https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: There is no function with that name. You want MessageBoxA or MessageBoxW. Best that you read the documentation right to the bottom. Mistake to use TCHAR. Bigger mistake to neglect error checking. Every day we wlhave tens of questions in the winapi tag from people that neglect error checking. Why?

Comment: I have tried both MessageBoxA and MessageBoxW, they return the same result. I did not get an error during compile time or run time, only the exception that i posted.

Comment: You didn't check for errors did you? Even then, you don't even assign to the struct in the global variable.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Once you do, you'll understand that you have two bugs. Both of them have been asked before, and received an answer. Down-vote, because *"this question does not show any research effort"*.

Comment: You're passing `API api` by value to `Tools::LoadApi()` so changes you make to this structure in that function will only affect the local copy, not the structure you pass in. If you're going to take on wrapping the Win32 API for some reason you should learn basic C++ concepts first.

Comment: @Jonathan Potter Yes i am passing API Api to Tools::LoadApis(), because what was defined in Tools::LoadApis was a local variable, which was used in the if statements

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`GetProcAddress` never throws /C++/ exceptions. The real problem is then you never check returned value stored in `Api._MessageBox`.

Also note that `MessageBox` in WinAPI is a macro expanding to either `MessageBoxW` or  `MessageBoxA` exported from user32. So it makes sense for `GetProcAddress(Api.User32, "MessageBox")` to return null.

On the second note there is an error in your code: you initialize an `Api` function parameter, but then use `Api` global variable (which is still not initialized). You should get rid of global variable and pass `API` by reference:

```
VOID Tools::LoadApis(API & Api)
{
   //...
}

int main()
{
    API Api{};
    Tools::LoadApis(Api); // not a part of the example
    if(Api._MessageBox)
    {
        Api._MessageBox(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
}
```